Extracting CSV only of coordinate and date of image with lowest NDVI value for points
I need to extract a CSV only the coordinate and date of the image with the lowest NDVI value, for each point.
var Alertas = ee.Geometry.MultiPoint(
        [[-52.97779569036378,-26.131082827324835],
         [-52.99290189153565,-26.165599631135546]]);

// load the S2 dataset
var S2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
  .filterDate("2023-01-01", "2023-12-31")
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 2))

// load S2_CLOUD_PROBABILITY dataset
var S2_CLOUD_PROBABILITY = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_CLOUD_PROBABILITY')

// Join S2_summer2018 and S2_CLOUD_PROBABILITY
var S2withCloudMask = ee.Join.saveFirst('cloud_mask').apply({
  primary: S2,
  secondary: S2_CLOUD_PROBABILITY,
  condition: ee.Filter.equals({
    leftField: 'system:index',
    rightField: 'system:index'
  })
})

S2withCloudMask = ee.ImageCollection(S2withCloudMask)

// define a function to mask-out clouds from each image
var maskClouds = function(img) {
  var clouds = ee.Image(img.get('cloud_mask')).select('probability')
  var isNotCloud = clouds.lt(20)
  return img.mask(isNotCloud)
}

// // use the maskClouds function  
var S2_cloudsMasked = S2withCloudMask.map(maskClouds)

// add NDVI
function addNDVI(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('ndvi')
  return image.addBands(ndvi)
}


//var NDVI = S2.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).reduce('min').clip(Alerta);
//Map.addLayer(ndvi, {}, 'NDVI');

// Map the function over the collection
var S2_cloudsMasked_ndvi = S2_cloudsMasked.map(addNDVI)

var points = ee.FeatureCollection(Alertas)
Map.centerObject(Alertas, 10);

var timeSeries = points
  .map(timeSeriesForPoint)
  .flatten()
  
var chart = ui.Chart.feature.groups({
  features: timeSeries, 
  xProperty: 'date', 
  yProperty: 'ndvi', 
  seriesProperty: 'point'
}) 

print(timeSeries)
print(chart)
Map.addLayer(points, null, 'points')


function timeSeriesForPoint(point) {
  return S2_cloudsMasked_ndvi
    .filterBounds(point.geometry())
    .map(function (image) {
      return extractNdvi(image, point)
    })
}

function extractNdvi(image, point) {
    var ndvi = image
      .select('ndvi')
      .reduceRegion({
        reducer: ee.Reducer.first(), 
        geometry: point.geometry(),
        scale: 10
      })
      .getNumber('ndvi')
    return ee.Feature(null, {
      point: point.geometry().coordinates().join('; '), //(,)
      ndvi: ndvi,
      date: image.date()
    })
}


You were pretty sparse in your description of exactly what you tried to do, so I made some assumptions.
I added an additional band with the fractional year for each image in the collection. I then reduced the collection, finding the min NDVI and the corresponding date. The argument to the min() reducer allows for this.
S2_cloudsMasked
  .select(['ndvi', 'fractionalYear'])
  .reduce(ee.Reducer.min(2).setOutputs(['ndvi', 'fractionalYear']))

Then I added lat/lon bands to the image and reduceRegion() with a toList() reducer to extract a list of pixel values. Note that this will not work for all that many pixels.
Finally, I turned the resulting dictionary into a feature collection, with lat/lon and fractional years turned back into formatted dates.
This collection can then be exported to a CSV.
var Alertas = ee.Geometry.MultiPoint([
  [-52.97779569036378, -26.131082827324835],
  [-52.99290189153565, -26.165599631135546]
])

var QA_BAND = 'cs_cdf'
var CLEAR_THRESHOLD = 0.60

// load the S2 dataset
var S2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_HARMONIZED')
  .filterBounds(Alertas)
  .filterDate('2023-01-01', '2024-01-01') // Remember that end date is exclusive!
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 2))

// Make a clear median composite.
var S2_cloudsMasked = S2
  .linkCollection(ee.ImageCollection('GOOGLE/CLOUD_SCORE_PLUS/V1/S2_HARMONIZED'), [QA_BAND])
  .map(maskClouds)
  .map(addNDVI)
  .map(addFractionalYear)

var minNdvi = S2_cloudsMasked
  .select(['ndvi', 'fractionalYear'])
  .reduce(ee.Reducer.min(2).setOutputs(['ndvi', 'fractionalYear']))
  
var lists = ee.Dictionary(minNdvi
  .addBands(ee.Image.pixelLonLat())
  .updateMask(minNdvi.mask().reduce(ee.Reducer.min())) // Ensure all bands are masked if one is
  .reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.toList(), 
    geometry: Alertas, 
    scale: 10,     
    maxPixels: 1e13, 
    tileScale: 16
  })
)

var count = ee.List(lists.get('ndvi')).size()

var features = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.List.sequence(0, count.subtract(1))
  .map(function (i) {
    var latitude = ee.List(lists.get('latitude')).getNumber(i)
    var longitude = ee.List(lists.get('longitude')).getNumber(i)
    var fractionalYear = ee.List(lists.get('fractionalYear')).getNumber(i)
    var date = fractionalYearToDate(fractionalYear)
      .format('yyyy-MM-dd')
    return ee.Feature(null, {
      latitude: latitude,
      longitude: longitude,
      date: date
    })
  })
)
  
print(features)

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: features, 
  description: 'min-ndvi-dates', 
  selectors: ['longitude', 'latitude', 'date']
})

Map.addLayer(Alertas, null, 'Alertas')
Map.addLayer(S2_cloudsMasked.select('ndvi'), null, 'NDVI time-series', false)
Map.addLayer(minNdvi, {bands: 'ndvi', palette: '#112040, #1C67A0, #6DB6B3, #FFFCCC, #ABAC21, #177228, #172313'}, 'min NDVI')
Map.addLayer(minNdvi, {bands: 'fractionalYear', min: 2023, max: 2024, palette: '#781C81, #3F60AE, #539EB6, #6DB388, #CAB843, #E78532, #D92120'}, 'fractionalYear of min NDVI')
Map.centerObject(Alertas)


function maskClouds(image) {
  return image.updateMask(image.select(QA_BAND).gte(CLEAR_THRESHOLD))
}

function addNDVI(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('ndvi')
  return image.addBands(ndvi)
}

function addFractionalYear(image) {
  var date = image.date()
  var fractionalYear = ee.Image(
    date.get('year').add(date.getFraction('year'))
  ).float().rename('fractionalYear')
  return image.addBands(fractionalYear)
}

function fractionalYearToDate(fractionalYear) {
  var year = fractionalYear.int()
  var fraction = fractionalYear.subtract(year)
  var daysInYear = ee.Date.fromYMD(year.add(1), 1, 1)
    .difference(ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 1, 1), 'days')
  var dayOfYear = daysInYear.multiply(fraction).round()
  return ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 1, 1)
    .advance(dayOfYear.subtract(1), 'days')  
}

I also switched from the S2 Cloud Probability collection to the new Cloud Score+ collection. It simply works better. Since you're looking for minimum NDVI values, you really want to be careful in removing as much cloud and haze as possible. Tweak CLEAR_THRESHOLD and QA_BAND (it can be cs_cdf or cs) until you're happy.
https://code.earthengine.google.com/b0ebf7b0a4efe95cfceba267089fef0d
